# Is a Corten steel planter strong enough to be used as retaining wall?

Tags: containers, landscaping, wall, erosion-control

My backyard is sloped with various boulders and retaining wall bricks used to create random terraces and slopes (I wouldn’t consider them terraces more like slopes).

I am trying to remove retaining wall blocks to create more space.

Is a corten steel planter or similar object be used to create a terrace? Or are blocks better because heavier?

[image: zoomed in]

[image: zoomed out]

Answer (score 1):

With minimum information in , one gets minimum information out. Corten is relatively high strength steel , with 50,000 + psi yield compared to 35,000 psi yield for ordinary hot rolled steel.It is intended for atmospheric exposure ( occasional wet , usually dry) , not buried or in a location where it is always wet. Steels are about 4 X heavier than concrete in density.
I had to search this item. When you fill one of the planters shown on the net with soil , it will hold back a slope. No add say how thick the steel is , so I guess about 0.030", that could last 10 to 20 years before rusting out from the inside wet surface. Rust from the outside will leave brown stains on anything like a concrete patio ; the rust would disappear on a grass surface. Of no significance, many are not likely Cor-Ten , a copyright name of USX.

Comment: Thank you blacksmith. Updated with photos. Sounds like it will hold up the slope but defeats purpose of rusting it to make it look better. The rust planter will blend in to mulch.

Comment: The Cotren will rust but but the rust will be more adherent than regular steel and will stop/slow rust on the atmosphere side. The complaint about Corten is if you build a bridge type structure there is some rust stain that runs down onto the supporting concrete.

Comment: Another huge issue is drainage. When using retaining wall block, the builders (should) create weep holes periodically in the block, especially in the bottom row. Often, builders will use drain tile on that row and, if it's a tall wall, at the three or four-foot level as well. Without proper drainage, the wall will fail, regardless of what's holding it up.

Comment: Thank you @Jurp !